# Weirdness with Yen key and backslash key on a Japanese keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, japanese

I've read about the backslash and Yen keys having weird functions depending on the OS or software that you use. But I figured it depends on the font you use whether it shows the symbol as a Yen symbol or a backslash.

But then why do *both* the Yen key and backslash key on my Japanese keyboard either both print the Yen or both print the backslash?

I find it highly redundant and I couldn't find any setting to adjust this. Is there really no way?